# Running Scala code from the command line

Tags: scala

Apologies as this is likely a dumb question but I am new to Scala.

Trying to run the following project from the command line

https://github.com/falconair/ComposingContracts

But getting the following

```
justin@justin-ThinkPad-X240:~/work/ComposingContracts$ scala src/main/scala/Main.scala 
/home/justin/work/ComposingContracts/src/main/scala/Main.scala:5: error: not found: value ComposingContracts
import ComposingContracts._
       ^
one error found
justin@justin-ThinkPad-X240:~/work/ComposingContracts$
```

The structure of the code *looks* like I should be able to run it from the command line. This *looks* to me like it's probably some kind of classpath error. But I don't know enough Scala to be sure.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to use the build tool [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) to build and run that code.

Answer (score 2):

As said by Jesper, you have to use `sbt` to run this code :

1. Install sbt ([here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Setup.html))
2. Go to the folder where is located the `build.sbt` file
3. Run the following command : `sbt run`

More information about `sbt` commands can be found [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Command-Line-Reference.html)

EDIT : as mentionned in the comments, you can use `sbt console`

> `sbt console` starts the Scala interpreter with a classpath including the compiled
>   sources, all jars in the lib directory, and managed libraries.

Comment: And if you need to play with your project, `sbt console` is more suited to the job than `sbt run`

Answer (score 0):

According to there is build.sbt file on the root of the project you should use [sbt](http://www.scala-sbt.org/) to run the program. For this simply use the following command from the project root directory:

```
sbt run
```

The command will compile the project properly and execute the Main.scala.